# To browse folder instead of files using uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uploadify

I need to upload files in a folder recursively.

Is it possible to use Uploadify to upload contents of a folder recursively by selecting the folder instead of selecting individual files in a folder?.In the below code i cannot able to browse folder.I am currently working in chrome.

```
$(window).load(
    function () {

        $("#<%=file.ClientID %>").fileUpload({
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.pdf;*.tiff;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': false,

        });
    }
);

<asp:FileUpload ID="file" runat="server" webkitdirectory="true" mozdirectory="true" directory="" />
```

Comment: folder browsing only works in chrome.

Comment: @dandavis i am working in chrome. when  i add flash it stopped working

Comment: yeah, i don't think the flash one has a folder option, maybe so it can be the same on all platforms...

Comment: @dandavis if i remove the js code it works fine

Comment: if you remove the js code, you just get the chrome browser folder input, but that's not wired to uploadify at all. you can iterate the chrome files yourself and send those many files using ajax, but that not gonna happen with the simplicity uploadify offers.

Comment: @dandavis Can u please send reference of send files using ajax

Comment: with(new XMLHttpRequest){open("POST", "/"); send(formWithFileInput);}